# Consulta de Intervalos de Fecha SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola soy principiante en SQL , estoy tratando de generar una consulta en los intervalos de dos fechas , Estaba intentando con Between pero solo me regresa datos con registros que tengas información en ciertas Fechas lo que yo busco es que Me devuelva 0 o Null en caso de que el  registro no contenga información

Es decir quiero saber si "ProductoA" tiene datos en intervalos de fechas de FechaA hasta FechaB pero quiero que consulte por cada fecha que hay entre FechaA y FechaB y NO que solo me devuelva valores donde si haya registros como normalmente lo hace "Where Between"

Ojala me pudieran ayudar.

Esto es lo que he intentado

```
Select DISTINCT(mtxnhist.PN),inv.LT,inv.MIN,mtxnhist.QTY,mtxnhist.TXNDATE
from mtxnhist 
LEFT JOIN inv on mtxnhist.PN= inv.PN
where TXNTYPE in (300,400) and
TXNDATE>= '2019-12-30' and TXNDATE <= '2020-03-03'
```

Y tengo de Resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces como la imagen de Arriba donde le "Producto 0201" aparece solo 14 veces porque solo en esas fechas campo QTY tiene un valor especifico Me gustaria que fuese asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega el código que has intentado sino posiblemente termine cerrada tu pregunta.

Comment: Vale, Editare mi pregunta @Bicho

Comment: Por qué no llevar toda esa lógica al cliente, la base de datos no es para implementar funciones complejas, quizás soporte pero a la larga no será eficiente por los bloqueos de tabla y controles que hace de forma interna, sin mencionar que tienes algunos detalles a considerar como que el rango de fechas no existe y tendrías que crearlo, o que `2020-01-01` no es igual a `2020-01-01 00:00:01`, entre otros. Suerte!

Comment: Si de hecho así lo he esta haciendo pero el proceso es algo  tardado y creí que si lo traía a nivel Base podría mejorar mis tiempos. aun así agradezco  el interés y la atención.

Answer (score 0):

Si creo entendí lo que quieres prueba moviendo tu condición como parte del `SELECT` en vez de `WHERE`:

```
Select
  DISTINCT(mtxnhist.PN),
  inv.LT,
  inv.MIN,
  IF(TXNDATE>= '2019-12-30' and TXNDATE <= '2020-03-03', mtxnhist.QTY, 0) as QTY,
  mtxnhist.TXNDATE
from mtxnhist
LEFT JOIN inv on mtxnhist.PN= inv.PN
where TXNTYPE in (300,400)
```

También puedes usar `BETWEEN`, ya depende de tí:

```
IF(TXNDATE between '2019-12-30' and '2020-03-03', mtxnhist.QTY, 0)
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Vlady, Creoq ue no me supe explicar,  La informacion que me interesa son los campos 

 mtxnhist.QTY 

Entonces quiero información de cada uno de esos campos por cada fecha que este en el intervalo. y si es Null  remplazarla por 0

Comment: Qué campo sería null y qué campo reemplazarías con 0

Comment: O sea, si la fecha está en el intervalo retornar QTY, si la fecha no está en el intervalo en el campo QTY retornar 0 ?

Comment: Es coreecto @Vlady

Comment: Ahí edité mi respuesta

Comment: Vlady, ya lo intente pero no me da el resultado que estoy buscando. 
ahora estoy intentando con lo siguiente 
`DECLARE @VFecha date=SYSDATETIME();
DECLARE @IFecha date = DATEADD(DAY,-120,@VFecha);
WHILE (@IFecha) < @VFecha 
BEGIN 

    Select DISTINCT(mtxnhist.PN),@IFecha,
 inv.LT ,inv.MIN,mtxnhist.QTY,mtxnhist.TXNDATE
 from mtxnhist 
LEFT JOIN inv on mtxnhist.PN= inv.PN
  WHERE TXNTYPE in (300,400) AND TXNDATE = @IFecha  
  IF (@IFecha) = @VFecha 
      BREAK  
   ELSE  
      CONTINUE 
END`

Pero no me esta devolviendo nada

Comment: Estás complicando algo que se ve simple, qué es lo que falla del query que te puse si hace lo que pides, mostrar todos los registros y poner QTY en 0 si la fecha está fuera del intervalo, puedes editar tu pregunta y poner un ejemplo de qué datos son los que deseas obtener.

Comment: Vlady ya esta editada mi pregunta espero darme a entender mejor. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Hola tienes que poner la condicion en el join para que te salga el resultado que quieres

```
Select DISTINCT(mtxnhist.PN),inv.LT,inv.MIN,mtxnhist.QTY,mtxnhist.TXNDATE
from mtxnhist 
LEFT JOIN inv 
    on mtxnhist.PN= inv.PN
    AND TXNTYPE in (300,400) 
    and TXNDATE>= '2019-12-30' 
    and TXNDATE <= '2020-03-03'
```